# Display checkbox and form data in a table on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/S4FT7/

I modified above jsfiddle example to get checkbox value to the table on the same page. The problems is it gives me the all checkbox  value that even not selected . some one give me help of fix this. thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select,input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
            st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $('#details').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in your fiddle example.

Comment: can you show your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `input[type=checkbox]` to `input[type=checkbox]:checked`

try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
    var st = '';
    $('#myForm input[type=text],input[type=password],select,input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
        st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
        $(this).val('');
    });
    alert(st);
    $('#details').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
   });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S4FT7/63/)

Answer (score 0):

I adjust some codes to make it simpler.

**$(':input')** can get any inputs, including your select.

if its checkbox your have to add **$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')** to get values which you choose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        var st = '';
        $(':input[type!="button"]').each(function(){
            if(this.value){
                st = st+ '<td>'+$(this).val()+'</td>';
                    $(this).val('');
            }
        });
        $('#details').append('<tr>'+st+'</tr>');
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/willHsu/S4FT7/64/)